# Ansible - negate Filter

Tags: filter, ansible, negate

I find some files with the find ansible module

```
- find:
    paths: "/"
    patterns: ["*.service"]
    file_type: file
    hidden: True
    recurse: yes
  register: find_results
  when: ansible_service_mgr == "systemd"
```

Now I want to check modify the Permissions on some of the files:

```
- file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
  with_items:
    - "{{ find_results.files }}"
  when:
    - item.path | match("/sys/devices/power/events/*")
    - ansible_service_mgr == "systemd"
```

The Problem is that I don't want a match. I want everything that don't match that path?

How can I negate the match filter? (!, not, etc.)?

Answer (score 9):

Thx for your help you can also do something like:

```
not (item.path | match("/sys/devices/power/events/*"))
```

Comment: So you need to thank by vote the answer if helpful, and accept the answer if it is right.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to rewrite your task as follows:

```
- file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
  with_items: "{{ [] if ansible_service_mgr != 'systemd' else find_results.files | rejectattr('path','match','/sys/devices/power/events/.*') | list }}"
```

1. It uses `rejectattr` to reject (eliminate) all items from `find_results.files` that match `/sys/devices/power/events/.*` regexp. A kind of match negation you wanted.
2. It makes a loop only with required items. Your task will make a loop with all found files and generate "skipped" message for each `when` statement miss.
3. Also it feeds empty list `[]` to `with_items` when service managed is not `systemd`. Otherwise your task may either generate multiple skipped items for each `find_results.files` item, or fail altogether because previous task was skipped and has `find_results.files` undefined.

P.S. If you have many tasks that depend on `systemd`, you may want to separate them into different yaml fils and conditionally include it only on `systemd` machines – this will make code much cleaner without those multiple `when: ansible_service_mgr == "systemd"` statements.

Answer (score 0):

can you try

```
when: ("/sys/devices/power/events/*" not in item.path "/sys/devices/power/events/")  and
      (ansible_service_mgr == "systemd")
```

But the second condition is useless because you already set the condition when getting the `find_results`